# Eclipse StarTeam plugin?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, starteam

Are there any decent plugin's for Eclipse that allow integration with StarTeam?

I miss the 'tight' intergration I used to have with CVS/SVN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Borland StarTeam has their own official integration with Eclipse:

http://www.borland.com/downloads/download_starteam_integrations.html

Answer (score 1):

Though it is called the StarTeam Eclipse Client, it is actually a plugin that requires Eclipse to be installed first